# Srcset WordPress. Ссылки на картинки с использованием https

Tags: wordpress, ssl, img

Проблема: Добавил сертификат сайту на WordPress, перестал отображаться логотип в футере.

В теге img логотипа присутствует srcset и он ведет на http как можно его изменить?

У большинства картинок на сайте применился mixedcontent, а у этого логотипа нет.

Ошибка:

Mixed Content: The page at '[https://сайт/](https://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/)' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image '[http://сайт/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/логотип.png](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF.png)'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Вопрос: как изменить http в srcset на https?

PS. http на https в настройках WP изменил.

Comment: Поправить вручную в шаблоне, не?

Comment: получение логотипа -get_theme_mod ('logo_img', false);

Вывод логотипа - echo esc_url ($ adrenaline_logo);  Что руками поправить?

Comment: без кода не скажу. выложите тему.

Comment: При переводе сайта с http на https надо менять все ссылки внутри базы с помощью специальных инструментов. Почитайте мой вопрос-ответ на эту тему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767561/220220

Comment: "http на https в настройках WP изменил." - этого совершенно недостаточно.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Спасибо, принял. Напиши ответом я лайк поставлю.

Comment: Да можно там по ссылке мой вопрос и ответ плюсануть

Answer (score 0):

> как изменить http в srcset на https?

Плагином https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/ или подобным изменить протокол своего домена. И только своего!.

А вообще нужно было использовать плагины миграции. Напр https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/ См поддробности https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767562/233741

Answer (score 0):

Я рекомендую использовать плагин https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/ он поможет избавится от смешанного контента